# Graph Classification via Random Forest

Tags: cheminformatics, machine-learning

I’m a medicinal chemistry undergraduate student who is preparing his dissertation. My idea would be to create a classifier that can distinguish anticancer drugs as active or inactive and distinguish those active in three classes, describing the molecules as a graph. My supervisor suggested me to use the [random forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest) classifier, and to do this I need to convert my graph into a vector trying to keep as many characteristics as possible.

I start from a molecular graph dataset like this:

```python
Data(x=[9, 9], edge_index=[2, 18], edge_attr=[18, 2], y=[0], smiles='COC(=O)C=CN1CC1')
```

where `x`, `edge_index` and `edge_attr` are a [torch tensor](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html), and `y` is the label (`0` is inactive, `1` is activity of class one, `2` is activity of class two, …). To run a random forest classifier I think I must convert them into a vector like a `np.array`, but I have no idea how to do it. Has anyone had experience on this task?

Comment: First, unless "activity class" is really a continuous or semi-continuous variable (e.g. are things in activity class 2 really _twice_ as active as things in activity class 1), you should switch to representing _y_ as a "one-hot" bit vector (for each molecule) or a "one-hot" matrix (for a stack of molecules) where the first column is a 1 if the molecule is activity class 0, the second column is a 1 is the molecule is activity class 1, etc.  Only a single 1 should appear in these columns; the rest of the entries are 0.  This is why it's called "one-hot".

Comment: Second, the most common approach to converting molecular graphs to vectors is called "fingerprinting".  There are many approaches to fingerprinting and many algorithms to do this.  Here's one somewhat gentle introduction to the topic.  https://rdkit.org/UGM/2012/Landrum_RDKit_UGM.Fingerprints.Final.pptx.pdf

Comment: You might also want to look into [Pytorch Geometric](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), a Pytorch derivative specifically built for Graph Neural Networks. Also, if you are new to machine learning in chemistry, [Deepchem](https://github.com/deepchem/deepchem) is an excellent library of chemical machine learning examples and tools.

Comment: This [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/basic-molecular-representation-for-machine-learning-b6be52e9ff76) has some good information. They mention graph2vec but it seems like it has to be pre-trained. A Morgan fingerprint might be the easier way to go.

Comment: Have a look at this example: https://github.com/deepchem/deepchem/blob/master/examples/tutorials/Introduction_to_Graph_Convolutions.ipynb . It uses DeepChem to generate the graph, but it also shows how the graph is fed into the machine learning model. Also, you may want to try some simpler fingerprints first, like ECFP, APFP, Mordred etc.

Comment: @Gianmarco were any of the comments so far helpful? Do you have any update on this question based on anything you've learned since asking it? If you figured out the answer, it would be useful if you could write a self-answer!

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.